# how to use join in this case

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables:

table pin_info:

```
id | member_id | look_week | look_name            | is_pinned | date 

1  |   1       |   3       | the improviser       | yes       | 2013-11-19 21:57:04
2  |   1       |   2       | destined for stardom | yes       | 2013-11-19 21:56:00
3  |   1       |   1       | fashinably corporate | no        | 2013-11-19 21:54:00
```

table arrow_rating:

```
id | member_id | look_week | look_name            | rating |

1  |   1       |   3       | the improviser       |   3    |
2  |   1       |   2       | destined for stardom |   4    |
3  |   2       |   1       | fashinably corporate |   5    |
```

I want **is_pinned**(from pin_info) and **rating**(from rating) .I will be having parameter member_id and look_week. (assume 1 and 2 respectively)

What I have done:

```
SELECT p_i.is_pinned,a_r.rating 
FROM pin_info p_i,arrow_rating a_r 
WHERE p_i.look_week=a_r.look_week AND p_i.member_id='1'
```

I am sure this is not the correct way.Any help?

Comment: Where do you want to join them on? What do they have in common? member_id? `INNER JOIN a_r ON a_r.look_week=p_i.look_week`?

Comment: member_id and look_week...its just that i know it will be having only one record..i am not able to frame the query properly..I am passing these two as parameters...thse are the field I have in common..

Comment: Take a look at my answer, if the result is not what you expect then please update your question to show desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT pin_info.is_pinned, arrow_rating
FROM pin_info INNER JOIN arrow_rating
ON pin_info.look_week = arrow_rating.look_week
WHERE pin_info.id = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT is_pinned, rating
FROM pin_info
LEFT JOIN arrow_rating USING (look_week, member_id)
WHERE pin_info.member_id = 1
AND pin_info.look_week = 2
```

That will select where both `member_id`s equal `1`, and `look_week` equals `2`

The result set for the above is:

```
is_pinned | rating
------------------
yes       |      4
```

Comment: the problem is i have a pinning and rating feature...i need to get the rating using week and pin using member_id..i am not sure if this will give the correct result..i can easily get them using separate queries,,but i want to do it in one query..

Comment: Based on your explanation I think it will work correctly. If not, then I must be having problems understanding. Can you show a desired result set in your question?

Comment: You say you can get them both with separate queries, what are the 2 queries that work?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question. You need to post example result sets: **what it *does*** vs **what you *want***

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41568/discussion-between-on-a-serious-note-and-drahcir)

Comment: final attempt...this is more clearer.....:give  is_pinned and rating ...i got to pick up is_pinned from pin_info and rating from arrow_rating......(i have mem_id and week values with me)...